# Accessing values in cross-crontact calling

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

I have followed this [tutorial](https://use.ink/3.x/basics/cross-contract-calling) to create a cross-contract calling in ink. There are two contracts in the example `accumulator` and `delegator`. The accumulator contract has two functions and the delegator contract can access those functions. But if I do an operation using increasing a value using the accumulator contract, then the delegator contract cannot access that value. The delegator contract can access only those values that are created by its functions though and not the values of the Accumulator. How can the delegator contract access the values generated by the accumulator contract?

The contracts of the accumulator and delegator can be found [here](https://github.com/stanlypalathingal/ink_trials)

Comment: When a smart contract call function of another smart contract, then it can read the state of another contract but modify state is not possible because smart contract operates on sandbox environment.

Comment: what do you mean by access the values? you can not access contract's fields directly, in this case you can get it with `get()` and increase it with `inc()` methods. The contract's state is encapsulated and only the contract can change its state via external calls

Comment: what i meant by accessing values is as follows: The accumulator contract increase the value using the ```inc``` function by 5. Hence the value is 5 if you use ```get``` function in accumulator. When i access the ```get``` function from delegator, it retruns zero and not 5. Is it possible to get the value set by accumulator contract in delegator contract?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting a different value is because the accumulator contract is instantiated twice. First, when you uploaded and instantiated the accumulator contract. Second, when you uploaded and instantiated the delegator contract.

In other words, when you increment the accumulator value directly through the accumulator contract, you are calling the first instance you created of the contract. When you call the `get()` message of the accumulator contract through the delegator contract, you are calling the second instance you created of the accumulator contract. This is because when you instantiated the delegator contract it also instantiated a new accumulator contract (see [code](https://github.com/Daanvdplas/ink-examples/blob/cacba92ad1fa78444fa87e9e85a02987cfb212d9/delegator/lib.rs#L62-L66)).

So if you want to call the `get()` message of the first instance of the accumulator contract through the delegator contract you need the `Contract` in stead of the `Code hash`, aka the AccountId of the contract. With the [`fn build_call()`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/call/fn.build_call.html) you then can build & execute a call to another contract. With the [selector](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/selector/) you can specify which message to call within a contract.